# tensorflow: how to convert a pt model to tensorflowjs layers model

Tags: javascript, tensorflow.js, yolov5, tensorflowjs-converter

I am implementing object detection in web page. I have successfully converted yolov5 pt model to web model by following command.

```
python export.py --weights yolov5s.pt --include tfjs
```

However it seems that converted model is a graph model which can only be loaded by loadGraphModel. How can I get a layers model which can be passed to loadLayersModel?